# Group / User based security. Table / SQL question

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I'm setting up a group / user based security system.

I have 4 tables as follows:

- user
- groups
- group_user_mappings
- acl

where acl is the mapping between an item_id and either a group or a user.

The way I've done the acl table, I have 3 columns  of note (actually 4th one as an auto-id, but that is irrelevant)

- col 1 item_id (item to access)
- col 3 user_id (user that is allowed to access)
- col 3 group_id (group that is allowed to access)

So for example

item1, peter, ,

item2, , group1

item3, jane, ,

so either the acl will give access to a user or a group. Any one line in the ACL table with either have an item -> user mapping, or an item group.

If I want to have a query that returns all objects a user has access to, I think I need to have a SQL query with a UNION, because I need 2 separate queries that join like..

item -> acl -> group -> user   AND
item -> acl -> user

This I guess will work OK. Is this how its normally done? Am I doing this the right way?

Seems a little messy. I was thinking I could get around it by creating a single user group for each person, so I only ever deal with groups in my SQL, but this seems a little messy as well..

Comment: I have a similar setup but do not allow users to be assigned roles, only groups, and then a user is assigned to a group. If it turns out there is only one user in a group, so be it, but it makes the whole thing easier to manage. And, realistically, how many groups are you going to have with only one user?
Also, there is nothing in your design to prevent a user having a permission assigned to them directly AND via a group. The role will then occur twice in your queries; plus you have to remember to check for direct as well as group access when you want to revoke a permission.

Comment: Thanks, I've felt that I will go this way if it all becomes too hard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 separate queries per se:

```
select
    * /* correct to columns needed */
from
    users u
        left join
    group_user_mappings g
        on
            u.user_id = g.user_id
        inner join
    acl
        on
            (acl.user_id = u.user_id or
             acl.group_id = g.group_id)
/* TODO - Add more tables, where clause, etc */
```

Comment: Cool that worked 8-) Is it a tidy or messy solution? Should I have 2 separate tables, one for user_acl, on for group_acl and union them together, or is this way OK do you think?